# Was never one for being jinxed

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

> Was never one for being jinxed

I can't understand the structure of this sentence and it's meaning.

Comment: The cited usage is very common in the exact (Past tense) form *X **was never one for** [doing Y]* (where ***Y*** is something ***X*** would never have ***wanted*** to do, even if *sometimes* he was forced to do it against his wishes). But it also occurs in the Present tense (rarely with ***never***) in usages like *My husband's not one for going out drinking on Friday night* - he doesn't do this [normally, or willingly] because *it doesn't appeal to him; he's **highly averse** to doing it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there was a pronoun or noun given right before the context you've given here.

For example,

James was never one for being jinxed.

The author is telling you that James does not want to be jinxed. You can exchange "being jinxed" with "ice cream" to clarify the sentence.

James was never one for ice cream.

So, yeah, James is not pro-jinx-ation.